# add code at class or function in python interperter

Tags: python

I like to use python interpreter, as it shows the result instantly. But I sometimes make mistakes. Like  misspelling or typing 'enter' twice during writing class or function. It's really annoying work to rewrite the code.

Is it possible to add some code to a predefined class or function in the interpreter?

Comment: Class, sort of. Function, not so much. You can bolt functions to classes.

Comment: You could monkey patch it, but why not just write and execute .py files?

Comment: No, but it is possible to rewrite all that piece of code simply by clicking on the first line and hitting enter.

Comment: Have a look at IPython and IPython Notebook, they are geared towards this type of interactive computation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a good way to achieve what you describe by just using the command line. 
But you can create a `script.py` file in the current directory and just `import script`. From there on out you are able to access all the defined functions and classes in the `script.py` file.

When you change something in the `script.py` you can use:

Python2

```
reload(script)
```

Python 3

```
import imp
imp.reload(script)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install ipython, it has the history function on steroids it does exactly what you ask, without adding code anywhere. If you make a typo or type enter twice, just use the "up arrow" and you get back all the class or function.